# localhost no longer works after setting default domain

Tags: windows, iis, dns, localhost

A program I need to run requires a FQDN to access the local IIS service.  Using localhost will not work.  The solution is to add a default domain "local" so that MACHINE.local gets me to the local IIS and satisfies the need for a FQDN.  Now, using localhost does not work.  Tried adding it to the hosts file.  Is there another way to get localhost recognized?  Running Windows 10.

Comment: Can you post the relevant configuration lines? Are you just trying to use a loop back address 127.0.0.1 for development? Have you configured the server to listen on address 127.0.0.1:whateverport you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem was that my Visual Studio .csproj continued to have references to localhost.  Changing those to .local resolved it.  As I share this project with others, I needed to uncheck the "Apply server settings to all servers" checkbox under Web Properties.  I still have not found a way to use localhost, but I no longer really need to.